# Rating column in a custom list form

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-form, list-form

I'm trying to create a custom list form for one of my lists using SharePoint Designer, and one thing i notice with the new form is that the OOTB rating column won't render.

What are the difference between the default dispform.aspx and a new custom dispform created through designer? Any snippet missing that hinder the rating to render correctly?